# web2py Autofilling/autocomplete returns id

Tags: python, ajax, autocomplete, web2py, autofill

i've a from and i want to fill it automatically based on information from a database and filled fields :

in db_wizard.py

```
db.define_table('receiver',
  Field('name'), # e.g. Daniel
  Field('email'),# e.g. daniel@daniel.com
  Field('opening'), # e.g. Dear Daniel
  ...)           

db.define_table('sender',
  Field('name'),  # e.g. John
  Field('email'), # e.g. John@john.com
  Field('tel'),   # e.g. 111 222 111
  ...)

db.define_table('letter',
  Field('sender', db.sender.id),     # e.g. Daniel
  Field('receiver', db.receiver.id), # e.g. John
  Field('opening'), # should be filled automatically when choosing/changing the value of "receiver"
  ...)
```

i use the plugin_lazy_widget

```
db.letter.opening.widget = suggest_widget(db.receiver.opening, id_field=db.i2l_receiver_profile.id, 
                                          limitby=(0,10), min_length=1, db=db(db.i2l_receiver_profile.user_id==auth.user_id))
```

but this widget or even the web2py_autocomplete_widget returns always the `ID` of the chosen record! and not what we really put in "opening", like the example above: it returns `1` and not `Dear Daniel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead :

```
db.letter.opening.widget = suggest_widget(db.receiver.opening, id_field=db.i2l_receiver_profile.id, 
                                          limitby=(0,10), min_length=1, db=db(db.i2l_receiver_profile.user_id==auth.user_id))
```

use:

```
db.letter.opening.widget = suggest_widget(db.receiver.opening, 
                                          limitby=(0,10), min_length=1, db=db(db.i2l_receiver_profile.user_id==auth.user_id))
```

that means not defining "`id_field`" will prevent it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use the suggest_widget (or the built-in autocomplete widget). Instead, you want the 'opening' field dynamically filled in as soon as the user selects a receiver. For that, you probably need a modified version of the [lazy_options_widget](http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_lazy_options_widget) (not used in conjunction with the suggest_widget).

Also, note that using an id_field with the 'opening' field wouldn't be appropriate anyway because it is not a reference field (so there is no associated id to reference).